# Swift Writing to and Accessing Class Objects

Tags: ios, class, swift3

So I am trying to use MapKit to put a series of points into a map. Ultimitely I am going to get a list of datapoints from csv and load them into the Location Class, then read them from the Class as MapView Annotations. This works here individually for plotting 2 points manually ...but I can't figure out how to properly load and access Location class for a number of items (10 Location Points for example)

Here is my class file

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation{
    let title: String?
    let locationName: String
    let discipline: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, locationName: String, lat: String, lon: String){
        self.title = title
        self.locationName = locationName
        let latDouble = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
        let lonDouble = (lon as NSString).doubleValue
        let latlong = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latDouble, longitude: lonDouble)
        self.discipline = locationName
        self.coordinate = latlong
        super.init()
    }
}
```

here is ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    //var stops = TransitStop[]()
    let initialLocation = CLLocation( latitude: 41.880632, longitude: -87.623277)
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let initial = Location(title: "YOU", locationName: "are here", lat: "41.880632", lon: "-87.623277")
        let firstStop = Location(title: "ashland", locationName: "ashland", lat: "41.88574", lon: "-87.627835")// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

        mapView.addAnnotation(initial)
        mapView.addAnnotation(firstStop)
    }

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you'll be getting all the necessary info from your csv including lat, long and the titles for the locations. <br>Get all items from csv to an array of model objects and just loop through the elements and init your `Location` object from the array values and add them as annotation.

Comment: conceptually I understand that is what i want to do. But I guess I don't have the correct syntax for doing this. Can you provide an example based on this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   var locationArray: [Location] = []
    for line in csvString{
        let values:[String] = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let title = values[0]
        let locationName = values[1]
        let lat = values[2]
        let lng = values[3]

        let latD: Double = Double(lat)
        let lngD: Double = Double(lng)

        let location = Location(title: title, locationName: locationName, lat: latD, lng: lngD)
        locationArray.append(location)
    }
    centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

    addLocationsToMap(locationArray: locationArray)
```

Make sure you do some validating on the values (`Double`) before implementing.
Then you can read the location into the map with this function:

```
func addLocationsToMap(locationArray: [Location]){
    for location in locationArray {
        mapView.addAnnotation(location)
    }
}
```

Note: I realize the OP doesn't need to explicitly define the variables. I just thought it would be easier to understand.

I assume the csv value can be read from an array perhaps and that the placement of the values in the csv file for 'title', 'loacationName' are well defined.

Comment: ok i'll accept this answer, this part went through ok, but the points aren't adding to the map. I think there's some issue with my Class file or how i'm formatting or accessing it.

Comment: Check the format of your CSV file and make sure your data (title, location, lat, lng) are where you expect and assign the value[x] to the appropriate variable. I now see that you do the conversion to `Double` in your `Location` class so you don't need to do it where I showed. Make certain the lat and lng values aren't switched. If you need any further assistance let me know. You could post an example of the csv file and we can go from there.